# Service worker throwing unauthorize 401 in http GET call

Tags: angular, httprequest, service-worker

I am working on an Angular PWA project and I am making some GET call using basic jwt authorization.
When I tried in Postman API is working fine with defined auth , but when I am trying to hit same APIs from the Angular application it is giving me *unauthorize access 401 from service worker*.

[image: Auth SW error 401]

I was going through few posts , blogs related to this issue , sadly I am unable to solve.

Any lead what changes must be done in order to approve by service-worker will be appreciated.

Till now I am doing basic GET http call in my service :

```
createAuthrorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')!);
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token!);
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    headers = headers.set('Username', username!);
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return headers
  }

  createStoreId() {
    const storeids = localStorage.getItem('storeids');
    return storeids
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = this.createAuthrorizationHeader();
    let id = this.createStoreId();
    var storeid = Number(JSON.parse(storeidd!));
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(storeid);
    return this.http
      .get(`${environment.baseUrl1}/api/List/${id}/0`, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(tap(res => {
        console.log(res);
        retry(2),
          catchError(this.handleError)
      }))
  }
```

Comment: can you please provide the logging - you are getting a 401 which is unauthorized.  this could be because the end point has not received the result - are you running a proxy on your angular project?  how are you forwarding the auth - we currently use universal express-engine and it was a bit painful to setup.

Comment: @chrisburd hi, no I am not running a proxy. I am not aware of it. I am using hosted production API. Still I need to do proxy setup ? Little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Actually I was not parsing json of Username from `localStorage.getItem('username');`

**Correction :**

```
const username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username')!);
```